# JQuery - ID not defined. Using a dynamic ID in a function?

Tags: jquery

I'm having a bit of trouble getting a script to work within a CMS. It's a relatively simple jQuery show/hide that was working fine until I needed to use it multiple times on one page. I tried to convert it to use each DIV's individual ID, but now it returns an error in Firebug saying

> id not defined.

jQuery

```
$('.articleSlide').each(function () {
var current = $(this);
current.attr("box_h", current.height());


$(".articleSlide").css("height", "250px");
$(".showHide").html('<a href="#">More</a>');
$(".showHide a").attr("href", "javascript:void(0)");
$(".showHide a").click(function() { openSlider() })

});

function openSlider()

{
    var open_height = $("#articleSlide_" + id).attr("box_h") + "px";
    $("#articleSlide_" + id).animate({"height": open_height}, {duration: "slow" });
    $(".showHide").html('<a href="#">More</a>');
    $(".showHide a").click(function() { closeSlider() })
}

function closeSlider()

{
    $("#articleSlide_" + id).animate({"height": "250px"}, {duration: "slow" });
    $(".showHide").html('<a href="#">More</a>');
    $(".showHide a").click(function() { openSlider() })
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="articleSlide" id="articleSlide_1">
  <p>We work closely with clients to provide effective solutions for a wide variety of products and applications through brand creation and management, video and motion graphics, marketing and advertising, digital and editorial.</p>
  <p>We understand markets and how to communicate in a multi-platform environment.We work closely with clients to provide effective solutions for a wide variety of products and applications through brand creation and management, video and motion graphics, marketing and advertising, digital and editorial.</p>
</div>
<div class="showHide">
```

**EDIT**

OK I think I misunderstood the ID bit I included. I basically wanted it to be able to pick up the individual ID of each show/hide div so it only opened that one. This is my current script that works, but if you have more than one div on the page it opens and closes them all

```
$(".articleSlide").each(function () {
var current = $(this);
current.attr("box_h", current.height());


$(".articleSlide").css("height", "250px");
$(".showHide").html('<a href="#">More</a>');
$(".showHide a").attr("href", "javascript:void(0)");
$(".showHide a").click(function() { openSlider() })


});

function openSlider()

{
    var open_height = $(".articleSlide").attr("box_h") + "px";
    $(".articleSlide").animate({"height": open_height}, {duration: "slow" });
    $(".showHide").html('<a href="#">More</a>');
    $(".showHide a").click(function() { closeSlider() })
}

function closeSlider()

{
    $(".articleSlide").animate({"height": "250px"}, {duration: "slow" });
    $(".showHide").html('<a href="#">More</a>');
    $(".showHide a").click(function() { openSlider() })
}
  <a href="#">More</a>
</div>
```

Comment: where is that `id` variable in the `openSlider` and `closeSlider` functions of yours defined?

Comment: I misunderstood how I thought mine was working. I've edited it now to be a little clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is quite clear. You use a variable `id` but never seem to define it.

Perhaps you meant for `openSlider()` to take an `id` parameter, and for your `.each` handler to pass `$(this).attr('id)` to `openSlider()`.

Same for `closeSlider()`.

Example:

```
$('.articleSlide').each(function () {
  var current = $(this);
  current.attr("box_h", current.height());
  $(".articleSlide").css("height", "250px");
  $(".showHide").html('<a href="#">More</a>');
  $(".showHide a").attr("href", "javascript:void(0)");
  $(".showHide a").click(function() { openSlider(current.attr('id')) })
});

function openSlider(id) {
    var open_height = $("#articleSlide_" + id).attr("box_h") + "px";
    $("#articleSlide_" + id).animate({"height": open_height}, {duration: "slow" });
    $(".showHide").html('<a href="#">More</a>');
    $(".showHide a").click(function() { closeSlider(id) })
}

function closeSlider(id) {
    $("#articleSlide_" + id).animate({"height": "250px"}, {duration: "slow" });
    $(".showHide").html('<a href="#">More</a>');
    $(".showHide a").click(function() { openSlider(id) })
}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to do the trick. I wanted it to when clicked on open the relevant DIV as oppose to opening them all the DIV's on the page.

Comment: @Yammi: You may need to declare a variable to hold `current.attr('id')` as well, to make the closure work. So `var current = $(this); var id = current.id;` and then pass `id` to `openSlider`.

Answer (score 2):

```
function openSlider()
{
    var open_height = $("#articleSlide_" + id).attr("box_h") + "px";
```

In the last line, what is `id` supposed to be?

You 've got the same problem here:

```
function closeSlider()
{
    $("#articleSlide_" + id).animate({"height": "250px"}, {duration: "slow" });
```

You need to modify these two functions to take a parameter specifying the element to work on (either by id, as the element itself, or a jQuery object) and change the `id` expression to refer suitably to that parameter.

Don't forget to change the lines

```
$(".showHide a").click(function() { openSlider() })
```

and

```
$(".showHide a").click(function() { closeSlider() })
```

to pass this parameter.

Answer (score 2):

on this line:

```
function openSlider()
{
    var open_height = $("#articleSlide_" + id).attr("box_h") + "px";
```

when do you ever define what the variable `id` is?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the complete picture of your scenario (I am bad at that), but here is something I feel is what you need... If otherwise, let me know and I will update to reflect what you need.

Assuming the following markup,

```
<div id=articlesContainer>

    <div class=articleSlide>
        <p>Crappety crappety crap!</p>
        <p>Feed me moar crap!</p>
    </div>
    <a class=showHideArticle>More...</a>

    <div class=articleSlide>
        <p>Crappety crappety crap!</p>
        <p>Feed me moar crap!</p>
    </div>
    <a class=showHideArticle>More...</a>

</div>
```

and the javascript

```
$('a.showHideArticle').click( function (e) {
    $(this).prev().slideToggle('slow');
});
```

*or* (my personal favourite)

```
$('#articlesContainer').delegate('a.showHideArticle', 'click', function (e) {
    $(this).prev().slideToggle('slow');
});
```

which is relatively better at performance, and will work with dynamically added articles too!

With this, whenever you click on a `.showHideArticle`, the corresponding `.articleSlide` should toggle ,ofcourse with a nice slide animation ;)

**Edit:** And oh, if you want to use `openSlider` and `closeSlider` functions (don't know why you would prefer that), then you may check if the `.articleSlide` is already visible, by using `if ($(this).is(':visible'))` and call `openSlider` or `closeSlider` accordingly.

Comment: and the *crappy* messages are just placeholders, no offense to what you wrote in that place in the question... this is what happens when one answers questions at midnight!

Answer (score -1):

$("#articleSlide_" + id) should more than likely become $("#articleSlide_" + current.id)